# Linear time construction of a data structure to answer in constant time if two strings have 2 common letters

Tags: c++, algorithm

Problem statement:

Given a string which contains words separated by blanks(spaces) it's required to construct a data structure in linear time (O(n) where n is the number of characters in the string) that can answer in constant time (O(1)) if two words in that string have two common characters.

Any ideas on how that data structure would look like?

Thanks.

Comment: No just a hard problem I've found and I can't find the optimal solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is ambiguous.

- What is the definition of a **word**?
- **Exactly** two characters in common or **at least** two characters in common?
- Do you just need to answer if a) there exists two words in the string which have two common characters or b) you will be given some pairs of words and need to answer if those words have two common characters for each pair?
- In case of (b) of point 3, what is the format of input? Will you be given whole word as input or just the indices of the words in the string?

I'm assuming a word consists of only alphabetical character (a-zA-Z) and you will be given arbitrary pair of words by their index in the input string.

Define array `f` such that, `(f[a],...,f[z]) = (0,...,25)` and `(f[A],...,f[Z]) = (26,...,51)`.

Let input string `S` consists of words `W[0], W[1], ..., W[n-1]`. Define a map from a word to integer by `F(W) = OR(1 << f[c]) for all characters c in word W`

If we have to find out if two words `W1, W2` has (assuming at least) two characters in common, we just need to find out if `B = F(W1) & F(W2)` has at least two bits. You can either loop over all bits of `B` to find if it has at least two bits, which is still `O(1)`, or you can check `B && (B & (B-1))` is true. (Explanation: `B & (B-1)` unset the lowest set bit of `B`, so if that is non-zero B must have at least two bits)

Now you can precompute `F(w)` for each word in `O(|S|)` and then output for each query in `O(1)` by comparing the `F`-values.

Comment: You assumed correctly that the alphabet is (a-zA-Z)*. Examples for words: in the string "apple orange" there are two words ("apple" and "orange"). The data structure should answer for any pair of words in the string if those two word have exactly 2 characters in common. Anyway... nice solution with only one addition that the map between a word and an integer should be a map between a word and a long long int because an int has only 32 bits and our alphabet has 52 letters. Thanks.